# c.replace is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

**Hi everyone**,

Actually, i got "c.replace is not a function" while  i was trying to delete some DOM elements and..i don't understand.

i'd like to delete some

tags from the DOM and so, i did it :

```
var liste=document.getElementById("tabs").getElementsByTagName("li");

    for(i=0;i<liste.length;i++)
    {
        if(liste[i].id==2)
        {
            $("#tabs").detach(liste[i]);
        }
    }
```

I tried .detach and .remove but it's the same. My version of jQuery is 1.7.1.min.js.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***order of iteration on a NodeLIst***

Doing forward iteration of a NodeList that is being modified when you remove an element can be an issue. Iterate in reverse when removing elements from the DOM.

---

***misuse of `detach()`***

Also, the arguments to `.detach()` do not perform a nested find, but rather act as a filter on the existing element(s) in the jQuery object, and should be passed a string. It seems that you actually want to detach the `li`, which would mean that you'd need to call `.detach()` on the `li` itself...

```
var liste=document.getElementById("tabs").getElementsByTagName("li");

var i = liste.length

while(i--) {
    if(liste[i].id==2) {
        $(liste[i]).detach();
    }
}
```

---

***`remove()` may be preferred***

Keep in mind that if you use `.detach()`, any jQuery data is retained. If you have no further use for the element, you should be using `.remove()` instead.

```
// ...
    $(liste[i]).remove(); // clean up all data
```

---

***code reduction***

Finally, since you're using jQuery, you could just do all this in the selector...

```
$('#tabs li[id=2]').remove(); // or .detach() if needed
```

---

***valid id attributes***

Keep these items in mind with respect to IDs...

- It's invalid to have duplicate IDs on a page
- It's invalid in HTML4 to have an ID that starts with a number

In the selector above, I used the *attribute-equals* filter, so it'll work, but you should really be using valid HTML to avoid problems elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks A LOT :D, it works, actually i can i have many <li> which have 2 as id so i did a loop.

Comment: @ThomasSaldi: You're welcome, but remember, it's invalid to have duplicate IDs on a page. You should be using a class instead. An element can have multiple classes if they're separated by a space character.

Comment: Okay, yes, you'r right, i gonna change this little thing. Have a good day

Answer (score 3):

`liste` is not (yet) a jQuery object. use `$(liste[i])`

or use

```
var liste= $('#tabs li');
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but is the id suppose to match the number 2.

```
var liste=document.getElementById("tabs").getElementsByTagName("li");

for(i=0;i<liste.length;i++) {
    if(liste[i].id==2) {
       $(liste[i]).detach();
    }
}
```

Since you are already using jQuery, why not just do:

```
$("li", "#tabs").filter("#2").detach();
```

Comment: Yes, i use the number 2 to aim the <li> tags i have to delete

Comment: An ID should normally not start with a number, try using "a2" or something, and check for strings not integers.

Answer (score 0):

```
var two = document.getElementById('2');
two.parentNode.removeChild(two);
```

Comment: For this forward iteration to work, you need to convert `liste` into an Array, otherwise it updates with the DOM change, and you end up skipping indices and iterating outside of the newly established bounds.

Comment: @amnotiam I realized that as soon as I posted it, but figured nobody would notice =p ...and, fixed